# Setting the project interpreter in PyCharm to Python 3.7 causes spurious code incompatibility messages about Python 3.5

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm 2017.2 highlights my `f`-strings with the message *Python version 3.5 does not support a 'F' prefix*.

But...

- In File | Settings | Editor | Inspections, *Code compatibility inspection* is unchecked, both for Default (stored in IDE) and for Project Default (stored in project). (I have seen other questions where the answer was about this point. Not applicable here.)
- Even if I turn *Code compatibility inspection* on and check only Python 3.6, I still get the message about Python 3.5.
- File | Invalidate Caches / Restart fixes it briefly, until the *Indexing* message goes away, then it comes back.
- I don't have Python 3.5 installed (only 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7). Python 3.7 is set as the project interpreter.
- This behaviour is new, since I started using Python 3.7 for real. If I change the interpreter back to Python 3.6 it goes away. I don't regard that as a useful workaround.

Either this is a bug I should report, or I am missing something that should be obvious. Anyone care to tell me which it is?

Comment: Have you tried with PyCharm 2018.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think PyCharm 2017.2 is too old and you should use PyCharm 2018.2. That old version was published before Python 3.7, so you may encounter troubles…